# Given $A^2-4A+I=0$, show that $ A^3=15A-4I$

Tags: matrices

If have a question like this , can we using equation method or deduction method to answer the question?? Or we need to answer the question by substituting the matrix??

Comment: Hint: $$x^3-15x+4=(x+4)(x^2-4x+1)$$

Comment: One thing to be careful of is just to remember that in general, matrix multiplication is NOT commutative. That doesn't come into play here, but if you are working with matrix equations containing multiple matrices you should be sure to keep that in mind.

Comment: @bburGsamohT This remark of yours might be one of the most useful pieces of information on the whole page. +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. So simply note that $A^3-15A+4I=(A+4I)(A^2-4A+I)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

From the first equation, you get $A^2 = 4A - I$

Now, multiply this equation by $A$. What do you get? How can you simplify that further?

Answer (score 0):

$A (A^2 - 4A + I) = 0$

$A^3 - 4A^2 + A = 0$

$A^2 = 4A - I$

$A^3 -4(4A - I) + A = 0$

$A^3 -15A + 4I = 0$

$A^3 = 15A - 4I$